# Why this example is stuck in an infinite loop in C?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, goto

In the example below, if I enter a character in Mac OS X terminal, the program will get stuck in an infinite loop, printing `Please enter a number:` line after line and never allowing the user to input anything. What's wrong with this code? What is the fix?
I want to change the code in a way that if a number is not entered, the user is prompted with an error message and asked to enter a number again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int number = 0, isnumber;
    getagin: printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    isnumber = scanf("%i", &number);
    if(isnumber) {
        printf("You enterd a number and it was %i\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("You did not eneter a number.\n");
        goto getagin;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I edited the code after reading the suggestions, and fixed the infinite loop problem. This is not a bad fix for the infinite loop problem, and with a simple for loop I tell C to search for any none numeric character. The code below won't allow inputs like `123abc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char line[10];
    int loop, arrayLength, number, nan;
    arrayLength = sizeof(line) / sizeof(char);
    do {
        nan = 0;
        printf("Please enter a number:\n");
        fgets(line, arrayLength, stdin);
        for(loop = 0; loop < arrayLength; loop++) { // search for any none numeric charcter inisde the line array
            if(line[loop] == '\n') { // stop the search if there is a carrage return
                break;
            }
            if((line[0] == '-' || line[0] == '+') && loop == 0) {
                continue;
            } // Exculude the sign charcters infront of numbers so the program can accept both negative and positive numbers
            if(!isdigit(line[loop])) { // if there is a none numeric character then add one to nan and break the loop
                nan++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(nan || strlen(line) == 1); // check if there is any NaN or the user has just hit enter
    sscanf(line, "%d", &number);
    printf("You enterd number %d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `goto` doesn't have anything with the issue here - the same would happen if he used a while loop.

Comment: So how can I change the code that if a number is not entered, the user is prompted with an error message and asked to enter a number again?

Comment: The goto has everything to do with why he doesn't see the problem,  imo...

Comment: @Bandrami read the discussion in Vaughn's comment - the same issue without `goto` keyword.

Comment: @Bandrami He doesn't know how `scanf` works when the contents of the buffer doesn't match the format string. Using a loop won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting infinite loop on entering a non-digit is the non-digit character left in the buffer as it is not read by the `scanf` for the next read of `scanf` (as it doesn't matches the format specifier). on next iteration `scanf` again finds this character and do not read it and exit immediately. This happens repeatedly and you are getting an infinite loop. Place a `while(getchar() != '\n');` statement to consume this character.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int number = 0, isnumber;
    getagin: printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    isnumber = scanf("%i", &number);
    if(isnumber) {
        printf("You enterd a number and it was %i\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("You did not eneter a number.\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n'); // T consume all non-digits
        goto getagin;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `getchar()` only works around the problem. When I enter `asdf 1234` (one line) into your program, I get four error messages before `scanf()` recognizes the number. IMO it makes more sense to read an entire line using `fgets()`, feed the resulting string to `sscanf()`.