# Why does this invalid input still works? (switch case) char error

Tags: c, switch-statement

UPDATED CODE

Why does the input 12 works? It interprets 12 as option 1 and takes 2 for the first scanf of case'1'? I do not want to use int opcao as if I enter a leter it will run indefinitly.

I want that the user can only exit the program when he chooses option exit (one of the cases) thus the do... while.If the user enters an invalid character or leter or whatever the menu shows again and shows the default message. I also want that after the chosen case is executed, it presents the menu again for a new choice thus i am using an always valid condition of 1=1 on the while. I can't use integers as if you enter a leter the program goes bonkers a.k.a never stops running. just try it.

```
char opcao;



do {
    menu();
    scanf(" %c",&opcao);

    switch(opcao) {
      case '1':
    printf("Massa do módulo (sem combustível):\n");
    scanf("%f",&m_modulo);
    printf("Massa de combustível:\n");
    scanf("%f",&m_combustivel);
    printf("Altitude no início da alunagem em relação a um ponto de referência:\n");
    break;
      case '2':

    break;
      case '3':
    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
    break;
      case '4':
    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
    break;
      case '5':
    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
    break;
      case '6':
    exit(0);
    break;
      default:
    printf("Opcao invalida, as seguintes opcoes estao disponiveis:\n");
    break;
    }
  }
while(1==1);
```

Comment: Use `opcao = getch()` instead of `scanf(" %c",&opcao)`.

Comment: `while(opcao!=1 || opcao!=2 || opcao!=3 || opcao!=4 || opcao!=5 || opcao!=6 && opcao>=1 && opcao<=6);` condition is always true.

Comment: In any case, you've got to make up your mind whether you want to use an `int opcao` or a `char opcao`.

Comment: When demonstrating a problem, always make sure your example obeys the "Minimal" in ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That means *shortest code* to demonstrate the confusion.  Clearly cases 2 through 6 are not needed (and have no code) so those could be cut.  But you also have many more scanf calls in case 1 than are needed to demonstrate the concern.  Please remember also you can edit your posts to make them more concise and informative with the "EDIT" button.

Comment: In the `while`  do you really mean `while((opcao != '1')||(opcao != '1') ...`?  The values you test in teh switch are ASCII '1', which = 0x31 or 49 (decimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're reading your input with a single `%c`.

This way, the first character of 12 (1) is used by the switch, while the second is used by the scanf of `case '1':`.

To avoid this behaviour, you can read the options as integers and use the placeholder `%d` in your very first `scanf`.

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid your infinte loop problem, you can do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clean_stdin();

int main() {
  int opcao;
  float m_modulo, m_combustivel;
  int flag = 0;

  do {
      printf("Make a choice: ");
      if (scanf("%d", &opcao) == 0) {
        clean_stdin();
      }
      else {
          switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                    printf("Massa do módulo (sem combustível): ");
                    scanf("%f", &m_modulo);
                    printf("Massa de combustível: ");
                    scanf("%f", &m_combustivel);
                    printf("Altitude no início da alunagem em relação a um ponto de referência.\n");
                    break;
            case 2:

                    break;
            case 3:
                    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
                     break;
            case 4:
                    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
                     break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.\n");
                    break;
            case 6:
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("Opcao invalida, as seguintes opcoes estao disponiveis:\n");
          }
      }

  } while(flag == 0);
}

void clean_stdin()
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

What I've done is the following:

- Check the scanf output if it reads the input correctly (in this specific case, if the input was a number it returned a number different from 0).
- Use the function `clean_stdin` ([Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318886/fflush-is-not-working-in-linux)) to clean characters that scanf read but didn't consumed (it expects a number and you give it a character, so the character stays in stdin and create the infinite loop)
- I use a flag to control the loop condition, when the exit option is chosen, flag value is changed to a value that makes the condition fail
- I added the `main()` because I need it to run the program; you can incorporate what's inside in your `main`. Remember to copy `clean_stdin()` function.

I suggest you to read some [scanf documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/scanf) to understand its return value.

I suggest also to read about `scanf` alternatives, since it's a boring function: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882489/why-does-scanf-get-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-on-invalid-input) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code).

Remember to format your code with the right indentation, it's a best practice.

Comment: Yes but if I enter a letter then the program runs indefinitly

Comment: @Leonardo Nunes: What does "runs indefinitly" mean? What exactly do you observe?

Comment: You need to handle the case in which you enter a `char` while scanf wnats an `int`.

Comment: @AndreyT it keeps reshowing the menu until infinity, I have to close the terminal for it to stop

Comment: That's because the `while` condition always evaluates to `True`. Simplify that like this: `while(opcao>=1 && opcao<=6)`. In this way, your loop goes on until a valid option is chosen. If you prefer the loop to continue when an **invalid** option is chosen, change the condition to this: `while(opcao<1 || opcao>6)`.

Comment: @boh I have chaged the while but it still hapens when the input is a letter

Comment: Switch to numbers. The condition is over a range of integers.

Comment: @boh , Nope. Try entering a character when `scanf` has a `%d`

Comment: Update the question with your new code, it'll help a lot.

Comment: @LeonardoNunes Try the solution :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @boh :)!Really well explained, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `scanf` works.

You asked `scanf` to read a single character from the input stream. The input stream originally contained `12` sequence (more likely, `12<newline>` sequence). So, just like you asked it to, `scanf` consumed that first `1`, leaving the rest in the input stream.

The next `scanf` continued to consume the input stream where the previous one left off.

Comment: how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` with the `%c` can read one character at once. '12' contains two characters '1' and '2'. So '1' will be consumed firstly by the `scanf` and hence,`case '1':` gets executed. The '2' is left in the input buffer(`stdin`) and it will be consumed by the next `scanf` with a `%c`.

To avoid this,you could declare `opcao` as an integer and use the following code:

```
    while(1)
     {
              if(scanf("%d",&opcao)==0)
              {
              printf("Invalid input. Try again:");
              scanf("%*s"); //remove the invalid input
              continue;
              }
              if(opcao>0 && opcao<7)
              break;
              else
              printf("invalid integer. Try again:");
     }
    switch(opcao) {
      case 1://your code
    break;
      case 2://your code
    break;
      case 3://your code
    break;
       // etc...
       case 6:exit(0);
             }
  //no need of do...while or a default case
```

Comment: So how can I avoid this?

Comment: @LeonardoNunes , Declare `opcao` as an `int` and use the code in my edited answer